# Git ve Terminal

Tags: git, terminal

I am new to the web software industry and I am trying to do it myself by learning from the internet. I am studying Computer Programming. I am working with Visual Studio code. My question is, what is the difference between TERMİNAL and Git in this editor?

git init
git commit

Answer (score 1):

No difference except one thing, GUI and CLI. GUI means Graphical stuff with buttons, input field etc.. and CLI means Command Line where you execute commands manually.

But as you're a beginner, so use Git in Terminal to master git properly. Git in VSCode is not recommended because it'll make you not to understand git properly.